# What volume does CO2 converted from O2 have?

Tags: mole

Let's say a human inhales air that contains exactly 1 Liter of pure O2 (about 4.76L regular air) and no CO2. All at normal pressure.
They manage to hold their breath until all the O2 has been converted into CO2 and diffused back into the air (of course unrealistic).
What volume will the CO2 of the exhaled air have?

My attempt:
A very trivial idea with the tiny amount of highscool Chemistry knowledge I thought of is to calculate through the number of Mole because we know that every O2 molecule will result in one CO2.

For O2: 1.331Kg/m^3 density and one Mol weighs 31.9988g.
Therefore the liter weighs 1.331g and has 1.331/31.9988mol = 0,0415953098241184 mol of O2

For CO2: 1.842Kg/m^3 density and one Mol weighs 44.0095g.
Therefore the resulting mol for the O2 will translate to 0,0415953098241184 * 44.0095g = 1.8305g

Which due to its density, takes a volume of... about 1L too?
Can this be correct?
It seems nonintuitive since we have many more atoms in the CO2 after all.

Huge thanks in advance :)

p.s. before someone claims this is for homework, I'm a software dev working on a game that shall contain a somewhat realistic simulation of the Pulmonary system :P

Comment: At the same temperature and pressure O2 converted to CO2 would not change volume. If warmer outlet temperature is considered, then volume is proportional to absolute temperature.

Comment: You treat both gases as ideal, and every ideal gas has same standard molar volume. More to the point, yes, it's (approximately) correct, as long as molecules have negligible volume. BTW even if it's for work or self study, things like that still fall under homework-type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the same temperature and pressure, oxygen converted to carbon dioxide by glucose oxidation would not change volume. If warmer outlet temperature is considered, then volume is proportional to absolute temperature.

$$\ce{C6H12O6(aq) + 6 O2(g) -> 6 H2O(g) + 6 CO2(g)}$$